# Comunicação entre o Android Studio e o Arduino

Tags: android-studio, arduino

Boa tarde!

Estou fazendo um aplicativo no Android Studio e tentando comunicar com o Arduino através da biblioteca Apache, como "org.apache.http.HTTPResponse" e não estou obtendo sucesso.

A todo instante o meu Android Studio informa que não pode abrir a biblioteca.

Algum dos senhores poderia me auxiliar.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Nos ajude colocando exemplos de código e/ou logs do erro.

Comment: Importo no Android Studio as bibliotecas abaixo:

Comment: import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

Comment: porém quando executo o programa, ele me dá os seguintes erros abaixo no momento da construção: 1) Error:(11, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist;  2) Error:(12, 30) error: package org.apache.http.client does not exist; 3) Error:(14, 38) error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist e 4) Error:(15, 35) error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist.

Comment: Detalhe: apenas reforçando que as bibliotecas estão no Main Activity e aparecem para mim em vermelho quando estou construindo, mas quando aperto Alt + Enter, o programa solicita a busca na Web, acha, instala, deixa de ficar vermelho na tela, mas não funciona, apresentando os erros acima.